# Given a cube ABCDEFGH, how many planes go through the cube's vertices and the point A?

Tags: combinatorics

I realised that you can choose 2 points out of 7 in total to get $\frac{7*6}{2}$, but there are some points that are coplanar, but I don't know how many planes i should subtract from the total number of planes.

Comment: I think the easiest way to count these is brute force. Just draw a cube and find the planes. Most of the planes contain four vertices. (You want "are determined by the vertices" rather than just "pass through" else there are infinitely many planes.) The general question for a $d$-cube would require systematic thought.

Comment: I think everyone can just brute force it since it's not that hard, I would like to find a systematic way

Comment: I agree that a systematic count (in all dimensions) would be nice. I'd think about counting planes according to the dimension of the facet of the cube they contain. I haven't time to work on this question now. In any case brute force for the cube would be the way to start, to check any general solution you found.